# How to exclude a specific column during the initial import of the file into R?

Tags: r

I am using RStudio and I am using the following `R` Codes to import a file into `R`. I need to exclude one specific column called "Approach".

Currently, my `R` codes to read the file stand as follows:

```
df1 <- read.csv("myfile.csv", check.names=FALSE, header = TRUE, fileEncoding="latin1")
```

I have tried something like this but it is not working:

```
excl_Approach_Col<-c("Approach")
df1 <- read.csv("myfile.csv", check.names=FALSE, header = TRUE, col.names!= excl_Approach_Col, fileEncoding="latin1")
```

I am getting the following error message:

```
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,
: object 'col.names' not found
```

I know I can import the full file as `df1` and then proceed to drop that specific column. However, it would be nice if I could exclude the column during the read file step.

Is this possible? Do I need any specific `package` to perform this operation?

Comment: Does `read.csv(...)[, -c(2, 4)]` help to exclude columns 2 and 4?

Comment: Use fast `fread` from `data.table` package with the option `drop`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use 'fread' in 'data.table' for loading select columns.  'select' allows you to pick columns, 'drop' allows you to exclude:

```
library( data.table)
a <- data.table::fread( 
     "myfile.csv"  ,  
    drop = "Approach"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use to import only certain columns

```
read.csv(file = "result1", sep = " ")[ ,1:2]
```

or if the columns names are known

```
read.csv(file = "result1", sep = " ")[ ,c('col1', 'col2')]
```

Answer (score -1):

`library( data.table)
a <- fread(
"myfile.csv",drop = "Approach")`

#### for multiple colunms drop use

`a <- fread("myfile.csv",drop = c("Approach","OtherColumn"))`

#### and to select specific column use SELECT in place of DROP.